# how to order an array in react native?

Tags: reactjs, native

I have to order this

```
("Forecast":["WP17 - CO746U100 - Wenceslao Escalante --- Telefonia - Implementaciones","WP19 - CO804U100 - Viamonte Nuevo --- Telefonia - Implementaciones","WP18 - CO663U200 - Corral de Bustos 2 --- Telefonia - Implementaciones","WP22 - MBA205 - Olavarria 2 --- Telefonia - Integraciones","WP23 - MC1165 - Martinez 4 --- Telefonia - Integraciones","WP26 - MC1881 - Bajo Flores 2 --- Telefonia - Integraciones","WP12 - FD454 - Shopping Mendoza --- Telefonia - Implementaciones","WP65 - TEST1 - TEST-TASK --- Telefonia - Integraciones","WP25 - MC1510 - Nunez 4 Av Congreso --- Telefonia - Integraciones","WP1 - UFO555 - Villa Maria --- Telefonia - Implementaciones","WP28 - MFO066 - CAC Formosa --- Telefonia - Integraciones","WP70 - 4312341 - sarasa --- Telefonia - Integraciones","WP71 - 54325 - sarasa2 --- Telefonia - Integraciones","WP75 - 00001 - Complejo Capitalinas --- Obras Civiles","WP76 - 00002 - Mejora de la Ca\u00f1ada --- Obras Civiles","WP32 - MCO800 - Unquillo Norte Nuevo --- Telefonia - Implementaciones","WP33 - MCO817 - Hospital Privado Nuevo --- Telefonia - Implementaciones","WP34 - LTF039 - Ushuaia Paseo del Fuego --- Telefonia - Implementaciones","WP36 - LSJ062 - San Juan UMTS 2 --- Telefonia - Implementaciones","WP37 - LCO261 - ZIPOLI NUEVO --- Telefonia - Implementaciones","WP63 - 7878 - SIAM SA --- Telefonia - Implementaciones","WP64 - MCF162 - Kansas Acassuso Test --- Telefonia - Implementaciones","WP69 - 11111 - Nueva Tare --- Telefonia - Implementaciones"],)
```

As it says there Implementaciones, integraciones and Obras.

Code:

```
  let ObrasV = []
  let ImplementacionesV = []
  let IntegracionesV = []

  if(this.state.dataSource){
    this.state.dataSource.forEach(function(DATA) {
      if(/^Integraciones/.test(DATA)) {
        IntegracionesV = IntegracionesV.concat(DATA)      
      }
      if(/^Implementaciones/.test(DATA)) {
        ImplementacionesV = ImplementacionesV.concat(DATA)
      }
      if(/^Obras/.test(DATA)) {
        ObrasV = ObrasV.concat(DATA)
      }
    })
    this.setState({
      Integraciones: IntegracionesV,
      Implementaciones: ImplementacionesV,
      Obras: ObrasV,
    })
    }
```

I am new to react native as I can do it?

Comment: i can tell u’re argentinian lol... sort it how? alphabetically?? u can use plain javascript for sorting

Comment: I have to order it in 3 lists for example:
Implentaciones: [ ]
integraciones: ["WP17 - CO746U100 - Wenceslao Escalante --- Telefonia - Implementaciones", "WP19 - CO804U100 - Viamonte Nuevo --- Telefonia - Implementaciones", etc ]
Obras: ["WP75 - 00001 - Complejo Capitalinas --- Obras Civiles", etc]

Comment: below he gave u a really good example on how to iterate and filter with javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a mix of [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to achieve it

```js
const data = ["WP17 - CO746U100 - Wenceslao Escalante --- Telefonia - Implementaciones", "WP19 - CO804U100 - Viamonte Nuevo --- Telefonia - Implementaciones", "WP18 - CO663U200 - Corral de Bustos 2 --- Telefonia - Implementaciones", "WP22 - MBA205 - Olavarria 2 --- Telefonia - Integraciones", "WP23 - MC1165 - Martinez 4 --- Telefonia - Integraciones", "WP26 - MC1881 - Bajo Flores 2 --- Telefonia - Integraciones", "WP12 - FD454 - Shopping Mendoza --- Telefonia - Implementaciones", "WP65 - TEST1 - TEST-TASK --- Telefonia - Integraciones", "WP25 - MC1510 - Nunez 4 Av Congreso --- Telefonia - Integraciones", "WP1 - UFO555 - Villa Maria --- Telefonia - Implementaciones", "WP28 - MFO066 - CAC Formosa --- Telefonia - Integraciones", "WP70 - 4312341 - sarasa --- Telefonia - Integraciones", "WP71 - 54325 - sarasa2 --- Telefonia - Integraciones", "WP75 - 00001 - Complejo Capitalinas --- Obras Civiles", "WP76 - 00002 - Mejora de la Ca\u00f1ada --- Obras Civiles", "WP32 - MCO800 - Unquillo Norte Nuevo --- Telefonia - Implementaciones", "WP33 - MCO817 - Hospital Privado Nuevo --- Telefonia - Implementaciones", "WP34 - LTF039 - Ushuaia Paseo del Fuego --- Telefonia - Implementaciones", "WP36 - LSJ062 - San Juan UMTS 2 --- Telefonia - Implementaciones", "WP37 - LCO261 - ZIPOLI NUEVO --- Telefonia - Implementaciones", "WP63 - 7878 - SIAM SA --- Telefonia - Implementaciones", "WP64 - MCF162 - Kansas Acassuso Test --- Telefonia - Implementaciones", "WP69 - 11111 - Nueva Tare --- Telefonia - Implementaciones"]

const result = ['Implementaciones', 'Integraciones', 'Obras']
    .reduce((total, category) => ({
        ...total,
        [category]: data.filter(line => line.includes(category))
    }), {})

console.log(result)
```

The resulting object will contain 3 arrays containing all your data

An easier to read implementation using `forEach` :

```js
const data = ["WP17 - CO746U100 - Wenceslao Escalante --- Telefonia - Implementaciones", "WP19 - CO804U100 - Viamonte Nuevo --- Telefonia - Implementaciones", "WP18 - CO663U200 - Corral de Bustos 2 --- Telefonia - Implementaciones", "WP22 - MBA205 - Olavarria 2 --- Telefonia - Integraciones", "WP23 - MC1165 - Martinez 4 --- Telefonia - Integraciones", "WP26 - MC1881 - Bajo Flores 2 --- Telefonia - Integraciones", "WP12 - FD454 - Shopping Mendoza --- Telefonia - Implementaciones", "WP65 - TEST1 - TEST-TASK --- Telefonia - Integraciones", "WP25 - MC1510 - Nunez 4 Av Congreso --- Telefonia - Integraciones", "WP1 - UFO555 - Villa Maria --- Telefonia - Implementaciones", "WP28 - MFO066 - CAC Formosa --- Telefonia - Integraciones", "WP70 - 4312341 - sarasa --- Telefonia - Integraciones", "WP71 - 54325 - sarasa2 --- Telefonia - Integraciones", "WP75 - 00001 - Complejo Capitalinas --- Obras Civiles", "WP76 - 00002 - Mejora de la Ca\u00f1ada --- Obras Civiles", "WP32 - MCO800 - Unquillo Norte Nuevo --- Telefonia - Implementaciones", "WP33 - MCO817 - Hospital Privado Nuevo --- Telefonia - Implementaciones", "WP34 - LTF039 - Ushuaia Paseo del Fuego --- Telefonia - Implementaciones", "WP36 - LSJ062 - San Juan UMTS 2 --- Telefonia - Implementaciones", "WP37 - LCO261 - ZIPOLI NUEVO --- Telefonia - Implementaciones", "WP63 - 7878 - SIAM SA --- Telefonia - Implementaciones", "WP64 - MCF162 - Kansas Acassuso Test --- Telefonia - Implementaciones", "WP69 - 11111 - Nueva Tare --- Telefonia - Implementaciones"]

const result = {};

['Implementaciones', 'Integraciones', 'Obras'].forEach(category => {
    result[category] = data.filter(line => line.includes(category))
})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply notice the `new RegExp()` and avoid using ^

```html
let ObrasV = []
  let ImplementacionesV = []
  let IntegracionesV = []

  if(this.state.dataSource){
    this.state.dataSource.forEach(function(DATA) {
      if(new RegExp(/Integraciones/).test(DATA)) {
        IntegracionesV = IntegracionesV.concat(DATA)      
      }
      if(new RegExp(/Implementaciones/).test(DATA)) {
        ImplementacionesV = ImplementacionesV.concat(DATA)
      }
      if(new RegExp(/Obras/).test(DATA)) {
        ObrasV = ObrasV.concat(DATA)
      }
    })
    this.setState({
      Integraciones: IntegracionesV,
      Implementaciones: ImplementacionesV,
      Obras: ObrasV,
    })
    }
```